# What is the best practice or style for writing Akka HTTP routes?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I find there are many ways to skin a cat, but what is the preferred style writing routes

```
def leaderboardGet1(): Route = {
  get {
    pathEnd {
      parameter('name) { name =>
        complete(. . .)
      } ~
      complete(. . .)
    } ~
    pathPrefix(base64identifier) { leaderboardIdentifier =>
      pathEnd {
        complete(. . .)
      } ~
      pathPrefix(base64identifier) { memberIdentifier =>
        pathEnd {
          complete(. . .)
        }
      }
    } ~
    complete {
      HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "Bad GET /leaderboard request")
    }
  }
}
```

I will call the first style match-least-first, and the the second style match-most-first. If someone knows better names please let me know.

```
def leaderboardGet2(): Route = {
  get {
    pathPrefix(base64identifier) { leaderboardIdentifier =>
      pathPrefix(base64identifier) { memberIdentifier =>
        pathEnd {
          complete(. . .)
        }
      } ~
      pathEnd {
        complete(. . .)
        }
      }
    } ~
    pathEnd {
      parameter('name) { name =>
        complete(. . .)
        }
      } ~
      complete(. . .)
    } ~
    complete {
      HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "Bad GET /leaderboard request")
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking more for readability/maintainability in coding style, but don't have a strong sense. I like the second style a little better as I can more easily see what the longest URL would be, but no other opinions.

There might be some performance considerations, depending statistically on what URLs are requested most, but I doubt that is significant.

Are there some other considerations pertaining to functional programming style, idiomatic Scala, idiomatic Spray routing, etc.?

Comment: Try reading routes naming convention https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

Comment: Thanks. Great reference, but not what I was looking for. Specifically, I was looking for how to define routes in Akka HTTP, and which of my two examples is the better style, or if the point is moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the styles above give you any advantage on code maintainability. If I had to pick one of this, I'd go with "match-most-first" approach. The reason for this is the first matched route is executed, so the more specific route definitions should go first.

Take this as an example

```
get {
  pathPrefix(JavaUUID) { id =>
    pathEnd {
      complete(s"Got UUID $id")
    }
  } ~ pathPrefix(Segment) { someOtherId =>
    pathEnd {
      complete(s"Got Other ID $someOtherId")
    }
  }
}
```

So, if `pathPrefix(Segment)` is handled first, `pathPrefix(JavaUUID)` will never get a result as it is matched by `pathPrefix(Segment)` too.